# What does "Reindexing blocks on disk" mean?

Tags: bitcoin-core

When I upgraded to 0.8.1, it said Reindexing blocks on disk and it took about four days (Grr).  But later, it said something about a corrupted database and it had to do it again! What is it doing?

Comment: I also have the exact same problem. My mac is a 2.3GHz Intel Corei5 with 8GB ram. So... not exactly a tree sloth of a computer, and it has taken a few days.. and now it is sitting at around 70% at not appearing to make any further progress.. I cant see any any errors being thrown, but.. if this is "normal", and I am a noob with bitcoins.. then this does not bode well at least for a Mac bitcoin wallet. Bitcoin v0.8.1-beta PS- Posting to Stackexchange using just an email address is simply impossible. LOADS of errors..

Comment: Does re-indexing re-download the block chain or is it done locally?
Because I am fast running out of ISP bandwidth because of this wallet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0.8x versions of the bitcoin-qt client now use a different database to store the blockchain.  This change was necessary to allow for larger block sizes.

The reindexing process is converting the previous database (which used BerkleyDB) into the new one (Which uses LevelDB).

Comment: Okay, but how come it had to do it again? It said something about a "Corrupted database".

Comment: @lurfjurv - Either something went wrong during the reindexing or your current copy of the old-DB blockchain is corrupted.  If it blows up the same way again, your best option would be to blow away the blockchain and redownload it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks, although I would like to avoid redownloading if at all possible; it took about 48 hours the first time.

Comment: @lurfjurv - As opposed to the ~96 hours you just waited for it to attempt to reindex?

Comment: Oh, I wasn't running the reindex all the time. It probably took about 10 hours total, just when my computer was open.

Answer (score 0):

The way the blockchain is stored on your computer has changed with the latest version.

The developers tweaked it, so that future users can profit from a faster init-proccess.

The new indexing made it necessary to reinitialize your blockchain.

However it should not have taken so long. On my laptop it took about 2 hours. Do you have a very weak computer?

Comment: I don't think so. It's  MacBook Pro, about 2 years old. Downloading the blockchain also took a long time (about 15 hours).